# Rotate an image and draw on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, transformation

I have been trying different ways to draw an image from a videostream of size 1920*1080 on a canvas of size 1080*1920. I want to rotate the video -90º so it fits exactly on the canvas (not resizing the original video by shrinking and expanding). The following is what I tried:

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.height = 1920;
canvas.width = 1080;
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(videoSrc, 0, 0, 1080, 1920, 1080, -1920, 1080, 1920);
// I have been trying different combinations of above numbers
return canvas;
```

I haven't used `context.rotate()` or any other translation method as I don't want to rotate the canvas but just draw the video starting from a different position in the canvas. Maybe I'm wrong. Thanks for reading

Comment: It's been a while since I use these, but I think it's normally done by rotating the context, drawing and then resetting the context.

Comment: you mean rotate my context so it has the same dimesions of the video, draw the video onto the canvas and then restore the original context?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call to `rotate()` within your context prior to drawing your image. Like so:

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.height = 1920;
canvas.width = 1080;

//Angle to rotate, negative for counter clockwise
degrees = 45; 

context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Rotation calculated in radians (hence the math).
context.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);

context.drawImage(videoSrc, 0, 0, 1080, 1920, 1080, -1920, 1080, 1920);

//Reset rotation
context.resetTransform();

return canvas;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is what did the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/EQx8V/